# exclude URLs when running a script

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using Firefox, iMacros and js.

I have a *URLs.txt*-file with a list of URLs. In Firefox I have a [webpage open](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2016-April/date.html) in Tab 1. This website contains many URLs. Some of which are in my text file.
I am trying to create a simple script that will skip the URLs from my text file and open the other URLs each in the next tabs. 10 at once. So Tab 2-11 should be opened with new URLs that are not in my text file.
This is my JavaScript, but it doesn't work:

```
var macro;
var ret;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE URLs.txt"+"\n"
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=HTM"+"\n";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}"+"\n";

iimPlay(macro)
var text=iimGetExtract();

 if(text.search("00016")!=-1)   {
 ret = iimPlay("donothing.iim");
   }

    else if (ret != -101) {
     ret = iimPlay("openURL.iim");
 }
```

openURL.iim simply opens tabs with URLs, but in this script it never skips those URLs that are in my list. I need help to fix this code.

this is what openURL.iim looks like (for the first 4 tabs):

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(2)>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(3)>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(4)>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(5)>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
....
```

Comment: I am online now. Please anyone who can help let me know.

Comment: your script can look totally different. I am only interested in making this work. Obviously my script is insufficient and partly wrong

Comment: I will make a nice donation to anyone who gets this done. I really need this

Comment: I can help you with this script. For more convenient conversations contact me via e-mail (see it on my profile page).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a clue. Let's make your txt-file with the list of URLs something like this:

```
"http://www.example1.com
http://www.example2.com
http://www.example3.com"
```

Pay attention to the fact that there are only two double quotes: at the beginning and at the end of this list.

So your script may look like:

```
iimPlayCode (
    "SET !DATASOURCE URLs.txt" + "\n" +
    "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}"
);
var excLinks = iimGetExtract().split(/\s+/);

var incLinks = [];
for (i = 1; i <= window.document.querySelectorAll("HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI").length; i++)
    if (excLinks.indexOf(window.document.querySelector("HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(" + i + ")>A").href) == -1)
        incLinks.push(i);

for (i = 0; i < Math.min(incLinks.length, 10); i++)
    iimPlayCode('EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>UL:nth-of-type(2)>LI:nth-of-type(' + incLinks[i] + ')>A" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"');
```

I leave testing this code on the target web site for you.

Comment: wow! Thank you so much. You did an incredible job! I just sent you an email. I would like to add a few more things to this. Please have a look.